# PHP Artisan Serve Not Working | PHP Artisan Serve Not Working Laravel |

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-artisan, artisan-serve

PHP Artisan Serve Not Working | PHP Artisan Serve Not Working Laravel |
[php artisan serve is not running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6zqo.png) 
By this problem can i use  this " php -S localhost:8000 -t public/ "

i used this instead of that command php -S localhost:8000 -t public/

Comment: Can you check your storage/logs folder?

Comment: What you see on http://localhost:8000?

Answer (score -1):

> [Artisan](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/artisan) is the command line interface included with Laravel. Artisan
> exists at the root of your application as the artisan script and
> provides a number of helpful commands that can assist you while you
> build your application.

Your project is installed on xampp. If you intend to install Laravel on xampp, read the following guide:

[Laravel Xampp Setup (Windows & Mac)](https://gist.github.com/bradtraversy/7485f928e3e8f08ee6bccbe0a681a821)

Otherwise, proceed as follows:
In general, there is no need to install Laravel on xampp. You can install your Laravel project in another part of your computer. Then use the above command in the Windows command line and using the cd command by going to the desired folder.

For example, I install my Laravel project as follows:

1- Installing PHP, MySQL and Apache(you can use xamppor wamp or any other program similar to these two programs or manually install and run these items in your system)

2- Composer installation (when installing Composer, you must choose the PHP installation location.) [Installation - Windows](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows)

3-Then open the command line in any part of your computer and enter the following command.

```
composer crete-Project Laravel/Laravel Test
```

4- After completing the installation, enter the following command to enter the Laravel installation folder: `cd/Test`

5-now run the command `php artisan serve`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).